# Autohotkey - Limit to only one hotkey execution at a time

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write an Autohotkey script that lets me press the keyboard keys fghjkl, with each translating to a left mouse-click. However I do NOT want them to be able to be all clicked at the same time (and thus counting as 6 mouseclicks), but only always one at a time.

I tried to achieve this by adding a small `sleep` period to each, but all this achieved was that I was able to press all at the same time, with the sleep duration stacking up...

How can I achieve what I need?

My current code is as follows:

```
f::
g::
h::
j::
k::
l::{
    SendInput "{LButton}"
    KeyWait "f"
    KeyWait "g"
    KeyWait "h"
    KeyWait "j"
    KeyWait "k"
    KeyWait "l"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **AHK v2**: <sub><sup>(Exact same code works in v1 as well with a tiny syntax change `HotIf` -> `If`)</sup></sub>

You can utilize context sensitive hotkeys:

```
#HotIf !A_PriorHotkey || (A_PriorHotkey ~= "f|g|h|j|k|l" && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 500)
f::
g::
h::
j::
k::
l::Click
#HotIf
```

Breakdown:
`!A_PriorHotkey || (A_PriorHotkey ~= "f|g|h|j|k|l" && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 500)`

- `!A_PriorHotkey`

  - If there is no prior hotkey (no hotkey has been pressed yet after this script was started)
- `A_PriorHotkey ~= "f|g|h|j|k|l"`

  - Check if the prior hotkey is <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, or <kbd>L</kbd>
  - Utilizes RegExMatch shorthand<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Variables.htm#regex)</sup>
- `A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 500`

  - If at least 500ms has passed since the prior hotkey was pressed (i.e. a click)